# fancyvrb:embedding Verbatim environemnt in new environemnt, default parameter not works

Tags: verbatim

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}  
\newenvironment{code}[1][5mm]
{\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{Verbatim}[xleftmargin=#1]}
{\end{Verbatim}}
\begin{document}
*****************************
\begin{code}[5mm]
code1
\end{code}
*****************************
\begin{code}
code2
\end{code}
*****************************
\end{document}
```

Compiling the above codes with `pdflatex` gives error:

```
! FancyVerb Error:
  Extraneous input `code2' between \begin{code}[<key=value>] and line end
.
\FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error:
\space \space #1
}

l.13 code2
```

If I add `[5mm]` after `\begin{code}` at line 13, it works. I wonder, why the default parameter in line 3 not works? How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm afraid this is beyond the ability of `fancyvrb`.